# Masters/Gurus Dying Of Cancer?

Tags: ramakrishna, ramana-maharshi, disease

Another thing I’ve found perplexing, thought I will ask, I’ve searched this on here many times.

Ramana Maharshi & RamaKrishna and several other masters and guru died by cancer. If they were so advanced masters and such, why would they die that way w/ so much illness and pain ?

Have come across two answers while trying to google this many times.

One is that they just let the cancer happen as what was meant to be, even though they had the means to remove it from their bodies. This was their decision.

The second explanation I come across often is that people like Ramana Maharshi & RamaKrishna took on the sins of their disciples. Which were so gross horrid sins that boom, cancer happened.

But they did this willingly and sacrificed themselves for their disciples & followers, is what some folks say.

Not sure if either of these is the case. Or could both be the case maybe ?

Is something else going on ? Is there some other explanation for their illness/cancer ?

Is it just very unfortunate karm-phal that no one can escape ? Not even these guys ?

Thx

Comment: I’m downvote queen this week  Is this not an ok question to ask ? All the posts I make are things I’ve wondered bout for long time, googled extensively and still didn’t find answers very well. Anyway, no probs, it’s all good, plz feel free to close/delete this and my Meera post if would be best, no worries 

Comment: I think it's a pretty alright question. Long life and immortality were never the focus of these people. Rāmakr̥ṣṇa and Ramaṇa especially really stressed their body a lot, not willingly, because they cared little about it and who knows if they were adequate nutrition (I doubt it). So, of course possibly some effects were generated.
I don't know about Jesus, and this is not the site to ask about him. Probably including Jesus in your question is what brought you downvotes. After all this is Hinduism Site, here, people don't care about Jesus and his life.

Comment: Rāmakr̥ṣṇa in his early days of blissful experience, really needed to be fed because he didn't eat. If he didn't eat, his body would have really died long ago. Now what else do you expect after such neglect of health. But these people also showed that body is perishable by nature, it is naturally afflicted by sickness and death. They didn't preach untruth by saying they are immortal or someone can be immortal, or that no illness could happen to them. These people didn't suffer crucification or any of that nonsense.

Comment: Remove Jesus from the question. It's not relevant here.

Comment: @Bingming Thx for your comments (detailed & so informative as usual) & also thx for telling me to remove the Jesus part, I didn’t realize that was problematic. Have edited it out just now. & yeah, I see your point bout RM & RK, re the perishable body, adequate nutrition, the sickness health situation. That makes sense. “They didn't preach untruth by saying they are immortal or someone can be immortal, or that no illness could happen to them.” <—— Ok, this is quite helpful in trying to understand the cancer illness circumstances as happened to take place w/ both of them. Thx 

Comment: Another thing to note is that Ramaṇa especially viewed Self to be eternal, and body being composed of substance is surely non-eternal and prone to death. That is in line with the view of ātman in Vedānta and other Vedic traditions.

Comment: @Bingming Yeah, very much so. When I first started to get into Hindu religious studies, I think Ramana Maharshi was one of the first books I tried to read, then Nisargadatta Maharaj, then lots of Kashmir Shaivism stuff. Embarrassing to say, but I prolly was able to understand about 10% of what I was reading, I think  Now trying to improve my understanding. Is slow going haha:D But I keep trying  Thx again for taking the time to write all these comments and explain, I appreciate it very much 